# How to protect REST API with wso2 IS?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, secure-gateway, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I now have a NodeJS REST API. It is CRUD service.
Does anyone know how to secure/protect my APIs step by step with wso2 OAuth2?

Comment: you can use WSO2 API Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to protect your REST API with OAuth2 use the WSO2 API Manager.

You can follow the [quick start guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide) to get started.
Details related to adding your API and enabling OAuth2 protection is mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-CreatinganAPIfromscratch) in the quick start guide.

Comment: But it seems like if someone know the actual CRUD endpoints, they can access & make changes directly instead of going through WSO2 API Manager. Am I right?

Comment: the basic idea is that you host the API in an internal environment and expose it to outside(internet) through the API manager.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!